# asp.net mvc cargar archivo

Tags: asp.net, http-post

En mi aplicacion tengo la opcion de elegir un archivo cualquiera y poder tomar el nombre del archivo, no tengo que guardarlo ni nada, solo su nombre, pero, tengo un problema y es que cuando cargo el archivo y le doy a enviar al formulario no envia nada, me dice que el valor del archivo es null y no entiendo el por que

este es mi modelo

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

namespace practica3.Models
{
  public class Estudiante 
  {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo no puede estar vacio")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo no puede estar vacio")]
    public string Matricula { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo no puede estar vacio")]
    public Carrera carrera { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Materia { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo no puede estar vacio")]
    //public string Practica { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            if (File != null)
                return File.FileName;
            else
                return String.Empty;
        }


    }
}

public enum Carrera
{

    Tecn_Software,
    Tecn_Seguridad,
    Tecn_Sonido,
    Tecn_Manofactura,
    Tecn_Mecatronica
}

}
```

Cuando estoy en modo debug o algo asi, presiono al lado izkierdo del visual studio y se marca como un circulo rojo, esto lo hago en la linea del if
     if (File != null)

Mediante esta herramienta obtengo todos lo valores y File me sale null y no entiendo el por que ya que selecciono un archivo

Este es mi controlador

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using practica3.Models;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;


namespace practica3.Controllers
{

public class HomeController : Controller 
{

 public ActionResult Registro_tareas(Estudiante estudiante)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();

        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Seleccionar Materia", Value = "1" });
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Programacion 3" });
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "DCU"});
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Auditoria informatica"});
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Programacion web" });

        ViewBag.Opciones = lst;

        return View();

    }

    public ActionResult Registro_exitoso(Estudiante estudiante)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(estudiante);
        }
        else
        {
           // string a = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Convert.ToString(estudiante.File));
            return View("Registro_exitoso");
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es mi vista

```
 @model practica3.Models.Estudiante
 @using practica3.Models

 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Registro_tareas";
 }

 <h2>Registro de tareas</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Registro_exitoso", "Home"))
{
// @Html.EditorForModel()

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nombre) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Nombre)<br />
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Matricula) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Matricula)<br />
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.carrera, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Carrera))), "Seleccionar Carrera")<br />
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Materia, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Opciones) <br />
  // @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Practica) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Practica)<br />
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.File) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file" })<br />
   // <span></span><input type="file" name="archivo" /><br />




<Input type="submit" value="Enviar" /> <br />


}
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder enviar un archivo por medio de un formulario debes ponerle el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

En razor quedaría así:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Registro_exitoso", "Home", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Si quieres saber un poco mas del atributo o relacionado [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST).

También te recomiendo utilizar el atributo post en tu formulario y método del controlador:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Registro_exitoso", "Home",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ // @Html.EditorForModel() 
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nombre) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Nombre)
  <br /> 
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Matricula) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Matricula)
  <br /> 
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.carrera, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Carrera))), "Seleccionar Carrera")
  <br /> 
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Materia, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Opciones) 
  <br /> 
  // @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Practica) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Practica)
  <br /> 
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.File) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file" })
  <br /> 
  // <span></span><input type="file" name="archivo" /><br /> 
  <Input type="submit" value="Enviar" /> 
  <br /> 
}
```

Y en el controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registro_exitoso(Estudiante estudiante) 
{ 
  if (ModelState.IsValid) 
  { 
    return View(estudiante); 
   } 
  else 
  { 
    // string a = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Convert.ToString(estudiante.File));
    return View("Registro_exitoso"); 
  } 
}
```

Si quieres ver el nombre te recomiendo que utilices:

```
var nombreFile = Path.GetFileName(estudiante.File.FileName)
```

Comment: muchas gracias, eso era lo que faltaba, muchas gracias